# Simultaneous powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ be coprime. Is is possible to have

\begin{align*}
a+b = x^n \\
b+c = y^n \\
c+a = z^n
\end{align*}

for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ a positive integer? If it helps, assume $n$ is an odd prime.

Comment: You can find $a,b,c$ from the above equations in terms of $x,y,z$ and ask if the so-derived $a,b,c$ are co-prime or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For instance $199, 530,$ and $801$ are pairwise coprime, and any two of them sum to a cube.

A smaller example is $36, 307,$ and $693$, which have no common factors for all three; but are not pairwise coprime.

Both examples were found with a computer search.